# How to instantiate effect with a wet setting in tone.js?

Tags: tone.js

How do I instantiate an effect with a specific wet setting? I want to be able to create a new synth with updated effect parameters upon a range input change. However, I can't figure out how to make the wet/dry balance be anything but 100% wet. Is there a way to create an effect with a specific wet parameter? Something along the lines of
`newDelay = new Tone.PingPongDelay(.5,.5).wet(.5)`? Or would I have to assign the effect to a variable and access it like `newDelay.wet = .5` after instantiating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an effect with a specific wet property, you can pass your options as an object like so:

```
const delay = new Tone.PingPongDelay({wet: 0.5, delayTime: "8n", feedback: 0.5});
```

Most Tone.js effects have different properties for that "options" object. You can find their documentation under the [Constructor heading](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/14.7.77/PingPongDelay.html#constructor) in the docs.

For instance, here's the reference for [PingPongDelayOptions](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/14.7.77/interface/PingPongDelayOptions).